# MAMP Apache server suddenly stopped working - no errors in the logs

Tags: mac-osx, apache-2.2, mamp

It worked fine and then it just stopped working. version 1.9.4

Comment: As a developer you surely appreciate detailed issue reports. We do, too. Mac OS X version, recent updates, hardware changes, did you restart between "worked fine" and "stopped working", what logs don't show errors etc.?

Comment: right, sorry... I managed to solve it, I'll provide an explanation below.

Answer (score 1):

A blank screen usually implies a Database issue, whether it's in your theme, your plugins, or a corrupted install of WP. Try disabling your plugins by renaming that folder under /wp-content and see if that solves it. That could narrow it down to a plugin issue. Try switching to the default theme by deleting or moving all the other themes from /wp-content/themes. That could single out a theme issue. Try re-installing WordPress to see if you just happened to have a corrupted installation. What host are you with?

Answer courtesy of [Micah Cooksey](http://profiles.wordpress.org/micahcooksey/)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was because I changed the name of the directory the files were saved into.

As a Mac user, I'm used to having the system take care of this for me. MAMP can't do this though. I changed the directory in Apache settings.

It works fine now.